# Advice needed on system requirements

Tags: sql-server, iis, .net

I want to set up some tools inhouse but just unsure of a few things.

I want to build websites (e.g. a wiki) that can be used internally by staff (there are approximately 300 staff members).

What would I need in terms of requirements of hardware software?

I've asked for Windows Server 2008, IIS7, .net Framework 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 Express. Is SQL Server Express good enough?

Ive been asked how many CAL's I will need. I don't even know if i need any - and for what? I am just planning on creating a few simple tools inhouse in the form of websites.

Can someone explain what the CPU, Memory and CAL's mean in this:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your staff are anything like ours (we have approx. 130 staff), then SQL2008 express will do just fine. No special requirements on the server hardware either. Since you are seemingly a Microsoft man, I would suggest using sharepoint.

As far as CALs are concerned, you'll need to check with your sysadmins what kind of licensing they have in place for your staff. Most likely they have a licensing scheme in place that covers all your basic needs, and the CALs for sharepoint would be part of that.

If you are not set on using Microsoft Products, I would recommend using MySQL for the database and any wiki of your choice (if it indeed needs a database, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software) for a comparison). A lot of them are OSS and do not require any licensing at all.

Comment: I dont understand what a CAL is needed for in this context? If i hosted a wiki with an external hosting provider then I would not be concerned with CALs - really not sure what it means.

Comment: btw we are using sharepoint for an intranet hosted on another internal server...

Comment: @raklos CALs in Microsoft-land can be hard to wrap your mind around. I suggest talking to a licensing expert at a reseller. Not here though, as licensing questions have been deemed 'too localized' because they change from location to location.

Comment: If you use sharepoint, then MS will require Client Access Licenses for that. They are cheap and often bundled together with other MS products in a Desktop package.

Comment: @wolfgangsz ah okay.. so for my own regular site built in asp.net that uses sqlserver(any version) CALs are not needed for end users? im just not sure from the link i gave above..

Comment: As far as my understanding of these things goes, that is correct. You are, of course, free not to use sharepoint and either use an OSS ASP.NET wiki or any other OSS technology. In fact, you don't even need a db server for some of them. Read the wikipedia page I recommended and then make your decision.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you want to do this with Microsoft products when you are building a website. I could understand if it had to inter-operate with Microsoft products, e.g. an email or file server, but not a web server.

Find the oldest box in the office, spend a couple of hours putting Ubuntu + apache + mysql + php on it and then some off-the-shelf software that will do the job. Wordpress with a small quantity of plugins may get you the functionality you need. You will be able to get the job done by teatime and the recycled hardware will cope fine with hundreds if not tens of thousands of users.

The above solution is something you will be able to setup and try in less time than it will take to get the purchase order signed off for that closed-source software from Microsoft.

Comment: -1 for "closed-source nonsense software from Microsoft". This is not a flaming site and you have no right to judge the internal policies of the company raklos works for (and in case there's any doubt on the subject: I am linux user and fan).

Comment: Now duly amended!